# Google Analytics error when changing protocol from http to https

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to change the protocol on google analytics from http to https.

[image]

But I can't and get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined
    at ga47Cc.ga4a.l9c (m=pm_base:15387)
    at HTMLElement.dispatch (<anonymous>:40:17183)
    at HTMLElement.m.handle (<anonymous>:40:15260)
    at p.CT (m=pm_base:8613)
    at m.kW (m=pm_base:8606)
    at q.CT [as invoke] (m=pm_base:8614)
    at m (m=pm_base:108)
    at HTMLElement.n (m=pm_base:108)
ga4a.l9c @ m=pm_base:15387
dispatch @ VM2347:40
m.handle @ VM2347:40
p.CT @ m=pm_base:8613
m.kW @ m=pm_base:8606
q.CT @ m=pm_base:8614
m @ m=pm_base:108
n @ m=pm_base:108
```

Anyone have any idea what it might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am also detecting the problem and also another user described a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785366/console-bug-with-switch-match-types-in-ga-goals/64786295#64786295) a while ago, I think it is a problem that we are all having and it is probably a temporary error in the Google Analytics interface.

*[EDIT] after a few hours it seems that the problem has been fixed*

Comment: After a few hours it seems that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Yes, seems now its working as expected. Will observe if it accrues again.