# Console bug with switch match types in GA goals

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

An error displayed in the console and I can't switch the match types in goals (Begins with, Equals to, & Regular Expression).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also detecting the problem and also another user described a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783925/google-analytics-error-when-changing-protocol-from-http-to-https) a while ago, I think it is a problem that we are all having and it is probably a temporary error in the Google Analytics interface.

*[EDIT] after a few hours it seems that the problem has been fixed*

Comment: After a few hours it seems that the problem has been fixed.